# Calculating the magnetic permeability of a known plasma

Tags: electromagnetism, plasma-physics

I have a plasma with known composition, temperature, and exact electron/ion/particle densities.

How can I then calculate a theoretical permeability of the plasma? Is this even possible? I assume that if I know the composition, I can work it out. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you be more specific, what kind of plasma is it? what is the direction of the magnetic field with respect to the electric field? That might help a bit

Comment: You would need to know the magnetic moment of each of the particles in the velocity distribution of particles in your plasma.  Then you could do an ensemble average to find the overall magnetic moment, if one exists, which is necessary to find the magnetic permeability, I think.  I should note that generally plasmas are treated as having a permeability equivalent to vacuum, but their permittivity is not (this is not to say that this approach is the "best" one, it's just the one most people use).

Answer (score 6):

You know you are asking a good question when it was the thesis question of [Niels Bohr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niels_Bohr) and [Hendrika Johanna van Leeuwen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hendrika_Johanna_van_Leeuwen). The relative magnetic permeability is $\mu_r= \left(1+\chi_m\right)$, where $\chi_m=\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}\right)_{H=0}$ is the magnetic susceptibility. The magnetization $M$, i.e. the magnetic dipole moment per unit volume, in a non-rotating plasma of uniform density is the statistical average of the dipole moments of each charge multiplied with the number density of dipoles, $M=n_0 \langle \mu \rangle$.

If the charges are **spinless**, they don't have intrinsic magnetic moments but could create magnetic moments by circular motion in a uniform magnetic field.  The kinetic dipole moment of a charge is $\boldsymbol{\mu} = \frac{q}{2 }\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{\dot{r}}$. The conserved Hamiltonian is
\begin{equation}
\mathcal H = \frac{\left(\mathbf{p}-q \mathbf{A}\right)^2}{2 m}+ q \phi\,.
\end{equation}
From Hamiltonian mechanics we get $\mathbf{\dot{r}}=d\mathcal H /d \mathbf{p}=\left(\mathbf{p}-q \mathbf{A}\right)/m$.
Substituting $\mathbf{p}_{m}=\left(\mathbf{p}-q \mathbf{A}\right)$, where $\mathbf{p}_m$ stands for mechanical momentum and $\mathbf{p}$ is the canonical momentum, we get $\boldsymbol{\mu}=\frac{q}{2m}\mathbf{r}\times \mathbf{p}_{m}$. We assume the magnetic field is $\mathbf{B}=B_z \hat{\mathbf{z}}$. The average kinetic dipole moment is
\begin{equation}
\langle \mu \rangle = \frac{\int \mu e^{-\mathcal H/k_B T}\, \frac{d\mathbf{p}\,d\mathbf{r}}{h^3}}{\int e^{-\mathcal H/k_B T}\, \frac{d\mathbf{p}\,d\mathbf{r}}{h^3}}\propto\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p_{m,x} e^{-\frac{p_{m,x}^2}{2mk_B T}}\, dp_{m,x} =0\,.
\end{equation}
This results in the [Bohr-van Leeuwen Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93van_Leeuwen_theorem), which states that the magnetization of a non-rotating system of spinless charges in thermal equilibrium is zero.

If the charges **have spin**, they have intrinsic magnetic moments $\mu_1$, with average value
\begin{equation}
\langle \mu_1\rangle = \frac{\int_{-1}^{1} \cos\theta\mu_1 e^{{\cos\theta\mu_1 H }/{k_BT}}\,d(\cos\theta)}{\int_{-1}^{1} e^{{\cos\theta\mu_1 H }/{k_BT}}\,d(\cos\theta)} = \mu_1 \left[ \coth\left(\frac{\mu_1 H}{k_B T}\right)-\frac{k_B T}{\mu_1 H}\right]\,.
\end{equation}
For plasmas we have $\mu_1 H \ll k_B T$, such that $\langle \mu_1\rangle \approx \mu_1 \frac{\mu_1 H}{3 k_B T}$ and $M=n_0 \langle \mu_1\rangle$. Therefore, the magnetic susceptibility is $\chi_m=\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial H}\right)_{H=0}=\frac{\mu_1^2 n_0 }{3 k_B T}$, giving magnetic permeability
\begin{equation}
\mu_r=1+\frac{\mu_1^2 n_0 }{3 k_B T}\,.
\end{equation}
For typical plasmas the intrinsic magnetic moment of charges is very small compared to the temperature, so that plasmas have effectively the permeability of vacuum.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I'm curious, does the phrase "typical plasmas" imply thermal plasmas? For a non-thermal plasma near room temperature, is the conclusion about permeability meaningfully different?

Comment: Sure thing. Yes, typically studied plasmas have thermal energies much larger compared to all other interaction energies, which makes them so popular. As it turns out, a gas of free electrons in a metal behaves a little like a high density cold plasma, so the non-thermal plasma at room temperature you are referring to would have magnetic properties that would indeed be very different from the above description and similar to those of metals