# Can an electron–positron plasma with $\mu_r=\varepsilon_r=2$ exist?

Tags: electromagnetism, plasma-physics, antimatter

Can an electron–positron plasma with [relative permeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permeability_(electromagnetism)#Relative_permeability_and_magnetic_susceptibility) and [relative permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_permittivity) of 2 ($\mu_r=\varepsilon_r=2$) exist? How dense would it be and how would its constituents move?

Can it keep those characteristics ($\mu_r=\varepsilon_r=2$) when moved? If not, can it keep $\mu_r*\varepsilon_r$ constant when moving?

Imagine a closed system where any energy exchange caused by electrons and positrons moving relative each other stays in the system.

Comment: A typical hot plasma has almost exactly $\mu_r=1$, see [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/169454/calculating-the-magnetic-permeability-of-a-known-plasma/371774); are you referring to a cold plasma?

Comment: @ZachJohnson I am unspecific in regard to temperature. Maybe your comment is an answer? Any bounding can fit as an answer.